# Install googleORtools on Eclipse on MacOS

Tags: java, eclipse, or-tools

Following the conventional way I have unpacked the binary file and add the jars into Eclipse project.

[image]

when I run the simple example model I got the following error reported:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/Platform
    at com.google.ortools.Loader.getNativeResourceURI(Loader.java:37)
    at com.google.ortools.Loader.loadNativeLibraries(Loader.java:105)
    at Test.Test_1.main(Test_1.java:189)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jna.Platform
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: The class `com.sun.jna.Platform` cannot be found since it is in the [Java Native Access](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.jna/jna) library not being on the Java Build Path. Probably more is missing. Are you following a tutorial?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/optimization/install/java/mac  there is no instruction on how to install googleortools on Eclipse.